# Chrome/Safari RTL

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, right-to-left

I've been asked to fix a menu in a RTL site. The elements of the top menu have RTL, text-align: right, and float right in the CSS, but the sub menu keeps aligning to the left in Chrome and Safari. I've tried negative left margins but it makes everything look even worse.

Link: http://daatsolutions.info/TA
User: guest
Pass: l0gin...

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: R u sure the pw is correct?  I can't seem to login.

Comment: I checked just now and the sub menu is aligned right in Chrome and FF.  I don't have Safari.

Comment: are you looking at it on a PC or Mac? It looks fine on my Mac Chrome (but *not* in Safari) but my client is using PCs and says the problem's still there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears fine on chrome(pc, latest ver). But in safari the menu seems to be aligned left. But the sub items are fine. 
The problem is that you have asssigned position:absolute to #access .menu-header .sub-menu in your css, this results in ignoring of the float property by safari, adding a style="position:relative" for each
        <ul class="sub-menu">
 should solve your trouble.
BTW, your page has many errors in html markup : I strongly suggest you fix it.
http://validator.w3.org/ should provide necessary help for that.
I also suggest that you try firebug (now also available for browsers other than ff) it's a lifesaver!